# Can we call External Rest API from Rule Chain to collect telemetry data from another API?

Tags: thingsboard

I am trying to collect energy generation statistics like Watts and wattHour form external API. I have External Rest API endpoint available for it.
 Is there a way in Thingsboard using rule chain to call external endpoint and store its as telemetry data. Later i want to show this data in dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been too long, but thingsboard has lacking documentation and it might be useful for someone else.

You'd have to use the *REST API CALL* external node (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/external-nodes/#rest-api-call-node)

If the Node was successful, it will output it's OutboundMessage containing the HTTP Response, with the *metadata* containing:
  - metadata.status
  - metadata.statusCode
  - metadata.statusReason

and with the payload of the message containing the response body from your external REST service (i.e. your stored telemetry).

You then have to use a *script* transformation node in order to format the metadata, payload and msgType, into the *POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST* message format, see: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/overview/#predefined-message-types
Your external REST API should provide the correct "deviceName" and "deviceType", as well as the "ts" in UNIX milliseconds.
Notice that you also need to change the messageType (msgType return variable) to "POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST".

Finally, just transmit the result to the *Save timeseries* action node and it will be stored as a telemetry from the specified device. Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the external REST API responds with XML format, not JSON?